# Override a function from app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php file into a Custom module

Tags: module, magento-1, custom, core

Recently I came across a site which contains some modifications in app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php file. I would like to keep code clean and move the changes to custom module in local scope; but as the functions.php file does not fall under any basic magento block, I don't know how to create custom module for it.

I would like to hear if you have encountered such problem before and you approach to solve it.

Any constructive comment is welcomed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

May be i have misunderstood your question but if you want to override use

```
app/code/**local**/Mage/Core/functions.php
```

But there are also reasons not to do this.

Comment: This means I will need to copy all code of the function, but I only want to override a part of it. Also, as you pointed serious issues to discourage this practice.

Comment: i think you should copy core code in local folder and then make your changes. Then you can check if everything works fine. Points to be remembered are (serious issues) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5978153/how-to-override-a-magento-function-in-app-code-core-mage-core-functions-php. just take a look at this link.

Comment: You are missing the main point here. Copying file is an approach but why copy things we won't be using?